# Which design pattern have to use for Object Creation?

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns

I have multiple Object classes(like Plot,Bars, Dial Box,flight Instrument). I am creating object from object Interface class.Object Interface class has all object class creating object and returning object to client.But adding objects and changing properties of object later on tedious job. **To resolve this which design pattern i have to use and how?** I get to to know i have to use Factory Design pattern sub classes will decide creation of object. in my situation m not getting how to do.

**client code**

```
 void GraphView::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)// client side code  
 {
  if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat(itemlistMimeType()))  
  {  
    if(event->mimeData()->text() == "Plot")  
    {  
        ObjInterfaceClass * pObjInterface = new ObjInterfaceClass ;// object creation  
        pObjInterface->CreateObject(CUSTOM_PLOT_NAME) ;  
        pObjInterface->DrawObject();  
    }  
  }  
 }
```

**Object Interface Class.h**

```
    class ObjInterfaceClass : public QObject
    {   
          public:      
             ObjInterfaceClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);  
             static  QStringList GetObjectDetails();
             static  ObjectPropStruct LoadObjProperty(char *pObjName);
             void                CreateObject(char* pObjectName) ;
             void                DrawObject() ;
    };
```

**Concrete class** like this concrete class so many are there

```
     class AlphaNumLabel : public QLabel
     {     
          Q_OBJECT
               public:
                  AlphaNumLabel(  int type, QWidget *parent = NULL );  
                  void setLabelText(int parameter);
                  void setLabelText(double parameter);
                  void setLabelText(QString parameter);   
              private:
                  QLabel *mpLabel;
                  int mLabelType;    
      };
     AlphaNumLabel::AlphaNumLabel(int type,QWidget *parent ): QLabel( parent )
     {   
           mpLabel = new QLabel(this);   
           mLabelType = type ;  
     }
```

[For more details see this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp0P1.png)
Any ideas or references are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Your class `AlphaNumLabel` is derived from `QLabel` AND has a member variable `QLabel`. I guess you need only one of that.

So, most likely the answer to your question is: Derive your `AlphaNumLabel` class from the interface (class) that you want to provide.

And, unlike Java, your interface class may contain real code, so you can add code that is the same for all your derived classes in the interface class. Or, you can make an abstract interface class (that contains only pure virtual methods) and derive an adapter class from it, which contains said shared code.

Your factory class/function can then return pointer to interface objects.
But, actually you should not return bare pointers. Use `unique_ptr<>` or `shared_pt<>` to make sure the objects are deleted when not needed anymore.

Comment: Thanks for reply, AlphaNumlabel class i have given it for the understand the scenario, like this so many object classes are there. every class i cant derive from interface class. is there any alternate ways

Comment: Then, maybe the decorator pattern is what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks .. I will go through this pattern... if you have any good examples share the link..